# Simple Amazon Affiliate Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, links

I am looking for a plugin that will embed my amazon affiliate id in outbound amazon links on my blog.

I've tried a couple of top plugins (e.g. sorted by popularity) and most are a huge overkill (e.g. providing image popups, search lists, products lists, price integration, etc...)

Can someone recommend a plugin that does what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using the plugin called **WordPress-Amazon-Associate**. It was easy to setup and has been working fine.

For more information:

- [link to the author's home
  page](http://labs.mdbitz.com/wordpress/wordpress-amazon-associate-plugin/)
- [link to the official WP plugin
  page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-amazon-associate/)